# Laravel. How to catch private channel authentication error on client side?

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I use custom guard for authentication on private channel as said here - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#closure-request-guards.
I try to debug my code, I return `null` intentionally in closure, in laravelecho logs I have:

```
could not be authenticated to private-channel.xxx
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

On client side nothing happens, I don't get any messages as it supposed to be. But I want somehow to catch that `"message": "Unauthenticated"` on client side to show authentication error message. How to do it?

This is how I connect to channel:

```
window.Echo.private('channel.' + userId)
    .listen("event1", (e) => { this._handleSockets(e) })
    .listen("event2", (e) => { this._handleSockets(e) })
```

This part is responsible for connecting *(rewrited for clarity code from above)*:

```
let socket = window.Echo.private('channel.' + userId);
```

But when I console.log socket I get always the same in both cases: when authenticated so as when not authenticated. How to catch status of authentication on private channel on client side?